# You must either configure a "public_key" or a "secret_key".[Symfony]

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I tried to setup a login authentication using LexikJWTAuthentication, I already generated the necessary keys

[image]

Here is how its called

config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key:'%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem' # required for token creation
    public_key:'%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem'  # required for token verification
    pass_phrase:'mafdhklkjkn234kas' # required for token creation, usage of an environment variable is recommended
    token_ttl:        3600
```

Here is return when I try to login, I used postman

[image]

Here is the var_dump of config in vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/DependencyInjection/LexikJWTAuthenticationExtension.php

[image]

bundles.php
[image]

Comment: are you sure you don't have `lexik_jwt_authentication` overwritten somewhere? show your bundles.php

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: @LuninRoman just added

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant yes i already did

Answer (score 1):

I pass the same error when passing a production, and honestly it's a bit silly. Cannot find keys because they are not loaded in configuration, ie dependency **"nelmio/cors-bundle"** was installed as dev.

By reinstalling it

```
composer require nelmio/cors-bundle
```

everything works again.

My apologies for my english

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and it was from "lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml" was not in my repo, after adding it, the problem was fixed.